# Save NSUserDefaults value when app is in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c

So, the app is in the **background**, meaning I didn't kill or terminate it, I just moved it to a background. Now, a notification comes in saying "blah, blah, blah" and that's the time when I need to set (save) a value as `NSUserDefaults` based on parameters that are brought with that notification:

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"pushType"];
```

And when the app comes back from a background I need to use that value for whatever reason.

Well, that **doesn't work**, the NSUserDefault is always **null**. It only works when the app is in the foreground.

Also, **Very Important**, I want it to work whether I bring my app to the foreground by clicking on the **notification** that just came up or by **clicking on the app icon**.

Supposed to be a simple thing, and yet this scenario is completely abandoned here. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: In what function are you running that code?

Comment: `standardUserDefaults` always returns a non-nil value. Where are you calling your function? Have you enabled a remote notifications background mode?

Comment: I'm calling it from `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and .. yes I enabled remote notification background mode. By the way I forgot to mention that I need it to work whether I bring my app to foreground by clicking on Notification or by clicking on the app icon.

Comment: hey mate can you paste the surrounding code?